# C - continue n times a for loop

Tags: c, shell, keyword

How can I use the continue keyword, to continue n times a loop. Like in shell we can do continue 2 to skip 2 iterations.
How is it possible to achieve this in C.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203695/discussion-on-question-by-newplayer55-c-continue-n-times-a-for-loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it using `continue`, but you can skip `for` loops incrementing the variable to skip `n` iterations.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
   if (some_condition) 
     i += nSkip;

    (...) 
}
```

Comment: If the `continue` is a bad practice as commented above, then this one I would say even worse. Messing with loop counter inside the loop is making the code very confusing.

Comment: `continue` is _not_ bad practice; you can of course use it in a messy way, as many constructs.

Comment: @Ctx I am tending to agree. Note the "If" in my statement :)

Comment: Bad practice or not, currently the OP appears to be asking exactly how to do that, and this answers that question (except for the missing `continue`). (Meanwhile I am not convinced that the question is currently what they mean to ask.)

Comment: Yep, modifying the loop iterator from inside a for loop is very bad practice... if there's a need for that, use a while loop and modify it in one single place.

Comment: But still, the correct solution would be `if (some_condition) { i += (nSkip-1); continue; }`, to be the equivalent. Or at least an `else` with the rest of the loop body

Answer (score 1):

This is at its root a programming style question, and those are always prone to opinionated debate.  Reader beware. :-)

C does not have `break(n)` and `continue(n)`.  This was a deliberate choice.  It was felt that these constructs are too difficult to maintain.  It's hard for a later programmer to count and keep track of the nested loops.  It's too easy for a later programmer to insert or delete a nesting level, throwing off the counts.

Veering down to the root of one of the biggest style debates there is, there are those who say that `goto` is evil and should never be used.  There are also those who say that `break` and `continue` are just goto's in disguise and that they should never be used, either.  Personally, I don't agree with either of those positions, but I *do* agree that `break(n)` and `continue(n)` have little to no value over pure `goto`; they're at least as confusing and prone to error.  So if you find yourself needing `break(n)` or `continue(n)` in C, and there's no other way around, it, just bite the bullet and use a `goto`.  The fact that you needed `break(n)` or `continue(n)` proves that you're doing something irretrievably ugly, so a `goto` won't make it any worse.

(Now, it's true, with that said, it's easy to replace `break(n)` with `goto out;`, but it's not nearly so easy. in general, to replace `continue(n)` with a `goto`.  So you'll probably have to do something else, and it'll probably be ugly, but again, by the time you get here, you're doomed to that anyway.)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530113/how-to-avoid-use-of-goto-and-break-nested-loops-efficiently) and its answers, although there the discussion is specifically about `break(n)`, not `continue(n)`.

Comment: A good statement; however, it looks like the OP indeed meant to skip two iterations of the loop, judging from the accept of the other answer...

Comment: re. `break` and `continue` being `goto`s in disguise, one could extend that argument to `return`, i.e., the value should only be returned from one place (the last line of the function body). But the same counter-argument applies to `break`, `continue` and `return`: the code without them often ends up with large parts deeply nested inside `else` branches. And of course one can further counter _that_, by further functions as replacements for the deep nesting, etc. =)

Comment: @Ctx (forehead slap) So he did!  Oh well, another excuse to launch into a canonical old debate about a programming style issue *not* averted...

Answer (score -2):

```
int i;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
   if (n<=2) 
     continue;
   else
      <do your task>
}
```

Comment: That's not what the question is asking for.