# break vs goto: Which is more appropriate in the following bool function in C?

Tags: c, break, goto

I wrote the following function which is meant to check if there is any non digit char in a string. The function must stop right after finding any non digit char and exit the loop and return true. Else, it will return false. Here's the code I am using: (ctype.h library is included).

```
bool isnotdigit(string argv)
{
    bool y = false;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv); i < n; i++)
    {
        char c = argv[i];
        if (! isdigit(c))
        {
            y = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

It can also be done this way:

```
bool isnotdigit(string argv)
{
    bool y = false;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv); i < n; i++)
    {
        char c = argv[i];
        if (! isdigit(c))
        {
            y = true;
            goto next;
        }
    }
next:
    return y;
}
```

If I am not wrong, both codes work the same way. Right? Then, what is the pros and cons of both? Especially in case of the bool function above.

Comment: A `break` is a `goto` in its gala clothes.

Comment: `break` is a strictly constrained `goto`, and those constraints are usually good. In this case they do exactly the same thing, but in other contexts the cavalier use of `goto` can produce cryptic code prone to subtle and devastating bugs.

Comment: superior: just don't have a `bool y`. you should just `return true` instead of `break` or `goto`, and `return false` at the end if no iteration already returned true. the `bool y` serves no purpose here. if you did that so you could only have a single point of exit from the function, it's time to realise that doesn't actually matter (unless you can profile it and prove otherwise in some specific situation).

Comment: @underscore_d *you should just `return true`*  Yes, you should.  Unfortunately, there are many environments that impose an "only one return point" rule in their code standards.  IMO that's utterly asinine and I've never found any empirical evidence that such a standard does anything but force the creation of convoluted code that force-fits simple-to-understand "square" algorithms like this into round holes, but they do exist.

Comment: @AndrewHenle loud round of sincere applause:)   Stupid rules:(

Comment: Hmm, and no one - including me - caught that in what's a "coding standard" question the use of the [CS50-addle-brained](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/addlebrained) `typedef char *string` abomination.  Lose that construct - hiding a pointer behind a `typedef` is almost always a really bad idea.  When you're trying to figure out what some code does, you ***need*** to know what the variables actually ***are***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a programming style question, and as such, you are probably not going to get a definitive answer.

Some say that `break` is just a `goto` in disguise, so that one is as bad as the other.  Some people say you should never use `break`.

But the whole point of `break` is that it's a guaranteed-to-be-unconfusing `goto`.  It always goes *from* the inside of a loop, *to* the outside of a loop.  (Well, except when it's part of a `switch` statement, of course.)

In this case, the `goto` buys you little or nothing.  So I don't think anyone would say that your second example is much better than your first.  (When there are nested loops, things can get more complicated.  More on that in a bit.)

And, finally, yet another way of writing your function is like this:

```
bool isnotdigit(string argv)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv); i < n; i++)
    {
        char c = argv[i];
        if (! isdigit(c))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But some people say that *thi*s is bad style, because (they say) a function should have exactly one `return` statement.  Other people, however, say that this is *good* style, because it gets rid of the extra boolean variable `y`, and getting rid of extra variables (especially extra little Boolean variables that just keep track of things) is a good rule, too.

Here are my opinions:

- `goto` can be confusing, and you almost never need it.  I almost never use `goto`.
- `break` is fine.  It's almost never confusing.  I use it all the time.  So I would very much prefer your first fragment over your second.
- Extra boolean variables, that just keep track of little things, can be confusing, *especially* when the only reason they're there is to get around some other "rule".
- I have no problem with multiple `return` statements, so I would always use something more like the third alternative, as I've presented it in this answer.

See also [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530113/how-to-avoid-use-of-goto-and-break-nested-loops-efficiently).

Now, in fairness, the argument against multiple `return` statements can be a good one.  *If* you've got cleanup to do before you exit, or if you ever have to add some cleanup code in the future, it can be very easy to forget to add it in both places (or in three or more places) if there are multiple `return` statements.  For me, when the function is small and simple (as it is in this case), I think the cleanliness (and the loss of the extra Boolean variable) outweighs the risks.  But if your metastyle is that you don't like judgment calls, if you like rigid rules that you can apply everywhere to avoid the superficial risks no matter what, then the "no multiple `return` statements" rule makes sense.

Finally, there's the question of nested loops.  The only justification I can imagine for the `goto next;` usage in your second example is that *if* a later programmer comes along and adds a nested loop, the code with `break` would probably not work any more, and would have to be reworked somehow.  By using `goto`, the rationalization might go, the code is more robust against that possibility.  (Personally, I don't think that's a good rationalization for the `goto`, but as I say, it's the only one I can think of.)

Once you have nested loops, the pros and cons (that is, `goto` versus `break` versus multiple `return` statements) definitely shift around, as discussed in the answers to [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530113/how-to-avoid-use-of-goto-and-break-nested-loops-efficiently).

P.S. Some languages "solve" the break-out-of-nested-loops problem by having something like `break(2)` that can break out of multiple loops at once.  C does not have this, and the reason is that it was felt to be too potentially confusing, and too likely to, um, break if a later maintenance programmer added or removed a level of nesting.

Or in other words, although single-level-`break` is a guaranteed-to-be-unconfusing `goto`, multi-level-`break` is potentially just as confusing as `goto`.  And, of course, you can argue with my characterizations here: after all, who says that `break` is *guaranteed* to be unconfusing?  It's not strictly guaranteed, of course, but that's because *any* language feature can be confusing if you use it badly.  (Case in point: extra little boolean variables that just keep track of various things.)

Comment: *If you've got cleanup to do before you exit, or if you ever have to add some cleanup code in the future, it can be very easy to forget to add it in both places*  That's just an argument for not duplicating code.  It's not an actual argument against multiple return points.

Answer (score 2):

They are functionally equivalent, but I would prefer to only use `goto` to break out of a nested loop, not a single loop.

`goto` is often frowned upon because it can lead to "[spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)", but it has its place in C for:

- Breaking cleanly out of a nested loop
- Resource deallocation, as so:

  ```
    char *buffer1 = NULL, *buffer2 = NULL, *buffer3 = NULL;

    buffer1 = malloc(1000);
    if(NULL == buffer1)
    {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    buffer2 = malloc(1000);
    if(NULL == buffer2)
    {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    buffer3 = malloc(1000);
    if(NULL == buffer3)
    {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    use(buffer1, buffer2, buffer3);

  cleanup:

    if(buffer1 != NULL)
    {
        free(buffer1);
        buffer1 = NULL;
    }

    if(buffer2 != NULL)
    {
        free(buffer2);
        buffer2 = NULL;
    }

    if(buffer3 != NULL)
    {
        free(buffer3);
        buffer3 = NULL;
    }
  ```

Comment: `  if(buffer1 != NULL)
  {
      free(buffer1);
      buffer1 = NULL;
  }` is not any different from `free(buffer1); buffer1 = NULL;`  as `free(NULL);` is a well-defined no-op.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The `NULL` check skips the overhead of calling the `free` function at all if it isn't needed

Comment: Until you've profiled your code and found that's an actual performance bottleneck, that's a needless and  premature optimization.  And for all you know (and you don't because you didn't profile the code...), the extra `if` check might wind up being slower.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `malloc`/`free` was just a simple, familiar, example of resource management for my answer; there are other resource management functions where `ReleaseResource(UnallocatedResource)` is *not* benign.

For example, I sometimes use the ODBC functions `SQLAllocHandle` and `SQLFreeHandle` with the same code pattern, and `SQLFreeHandle(x, SQL_NULL_HANDLE);` *will* cause an error, so in that case the check is needed. Good to include the check since sometimes you will actually need it with this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `goto` if there are alternatives.

But in this function you need neither, just `return` when the result is clear:

```
bool isnotdigit(string argv)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv); i < n; i++)
    {
        char c = argv[i];
        if (! isdigit(c))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Functions with multiple exit points can lead to defects when taken over by maintainers. Someone unfamiliar with the code may make a mistake when trying to fix a defect because they overlook one or more of the exit paths.

Comment: @SakibArifin Why would the _program_ end? The _function_ is all that ends, by returning the value it was told to `return`.

Comment: @DavidCullen If new maintainers would be confused by multiple exit points, I think that just means the function is too large independent of how it returns... or perhaps the new maintainers just aren't ready for the job they've been given.

Comment: @DavidCullen Cramming this algorithm into a one-size-fits-all "one return point" rule does nothing but lead to more complex and therefore more-bug-prone code.

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry, by program I meant the function.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree, but as I wrote in my answer, "If your metastyle is that you don't like judgment calls, if you like rigid rules that you can apply everywhere to avoid the superficial risks no matter what, then the 'no multiple return statements' rule makes sense."  If you ban multiple `return` statements, you will never have a bug due to forgetting a cleanup action on one of them.  If you ban hammers, no one will ever hit their thumb with one.

Comment: @SteveSummit A "don't duplicate code" standard covers the case of having to run cleanup code.  A "single return point" rules is more akin to "don't turn screws to the left when driving them".  What if you then have to drive a left-hand screw?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Don't worry, I'm not disagreeing with you.  I'm just explaining where the one-size-fits-all rules (that I detest, also) come from.  (And your "what if" is easily dispensed with: in most of the world, there simply are no left-hand screws.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Fair enough.  FWIW, I've worked in environments with that "one return point" rule, and it really does lead to convoluted code in many cases.  Which is why I think it's probably one of the most useless rules that I've seen in code standards.

Comment: @underscore_d Even in small functions, someone who is not the original author can overlook a return. Also, I am not saying that having a single exit point should be a rule. I am just pointing out a potential pitfall. And now this comment section has become irrelevant to the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

At least in a simple case as in your example I suggest to avoid both `goto` and `break` and add the condition to the `for` statement instead. (This may be a matter of personal preference or coding guidelines that might apply to your project.)

```
bool isnotdigit(string argv)
{
    bool y = false;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv); (i < n) && !y; i++)
    {
        char c = argv[i];

        /* or alternatively: y = ! isdigit(c); */
        if (! isdigit(c))
        {
            y = true;
        }
    }

    return y;
}
```

BTW: I suggest to rename the function argument, because `argv` can be confused with the standard arguments of the `main` function which are often called `argc` and `argv`. Instead of `y` I would suggest a meaningful name, e.g. `wrong_char_found`